# SSIS Excel Destination Formatting

Tags: excel, ssis

I have an issue when attempting to write the results of 2 queries into 2 different sheets in a single Excel Workbook.  The job uses a template file which it copies into a date-stamped version.  The 2 sheets are named and pre-formatted with a header row.  The 2 queries are extracting data from the same table.

The problem is as follows:

The first query populates sheet1.  It skips a row after the headers and writes everything in unformatted text.

The second query populates sheet2.  The data starts in the row immediately after the header, but for some reason all of the data picks up the formatting of the header row.

One thing I've observed is that the order of processing determines which one has the formatting issue.  I have switched the order of the 2 Data Flow tasks around but it is always the second one to be processed that has the issue.

I've linked to an image of some sample results.

[image: Sample Results]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you might have.

Comment: What have you tried, add a snapchot or describe your ssis package

Comment: Create a script task, open the file, and programmatically format the cells.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  @Hadi my ssis package has a task to copy a formatted Excel template, followed by 2 Data Flow tasks which populate each of the 2 worksheets in the Excel template.  These 2 tasks are identical procedures, the only difference is the fields they extract from the database and the sheet name that they export to.  For some reason the second Data Flow task always fills in the data with the formatting of the header row.  It doesn't matter which order I put these tasks in, it's always the one that is second that has this issue.

Comment: @manderson I am not very experienced with scripting in SSIS but no time like the present to learn!  Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to let you all know that I was able to solve this issue.  I am fortunate to have the CozyRoc tools installed on my servers, so I used the Excel Destination Plus task from their library.  I was able to set the exact row and column where I wanted my data to start writing, and with this method it did not pick up the header formatting.  Thanks again for your replies!